# How to access constants value in another swift class

Tags: ios, swift, constants

how to get constant #define value in swift class.
I have created constant.h class in my project, here I created the screen width and hight two constants values.

Constant.h

```
#define SCREEN_WIDTH_SWIFT          UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width
#define SCREEN_HEIGHT_SWIFT         UIScreen.main.bounds.size.height
```

Now i want to asses SCREEN_HEIGHT_SWIFT in ViewController.swift class

```
NSFontAttributeName : UIFont(name: "GillSans-Light" , size: MS_SCREEN_HEIGHT_SWIFT/40.5)!,NSForegroundColorAttributeName : UIColor.white
```

Comment: you are using both objective C and swift in single proj

Comment: Yes I am using both objective-C and swift in single project.  Is that bad?

Comment: no no not like....

Comment: try this  `Constant.SCREEN_HEIGHT_SWIFT`, for e.g `NSFontAttributeName : UIFont(name: "GillSans-Light" , size: Constant.SCREEN_HEIGHT_SWIFT/40.5)`

Comment: `let screenWidth = UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width`

Comment: @kiran - your problm is solved or not, are you verified my answer

Answer (score 3):

`#define` creates a C style compiler macro, not a constant. Swift doesn't support C compiler macros. You will need to use an actual constant.

Answer (score 0):

Hi instead of using `#define` use `let` and assign the values with a `=`:

```
let SCREEN_WIDTH_SWIFT = UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width
let SCREEN_HEIGHT_SWIFT = UIScreen.main.bounds.size.height
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply create separate class to maintain your all constants.
Lets say **AppConstats** is your class. Then create your constants like this:

```
static let SCREEN_WIDTH = UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width
```

Now wherever you want to access your constant, simply use like this:

```
AppConstats.SCREEN_WIDTH
```

Comment: Tried that ... Xcode says 'AppConstants' is out of scope

Comment: @BrianReinhold Check where you have placed your AppConstants class. That might be because access control might have imposed on the class. Make sure your class is available within the project. You can try by keeping in at the level where your Plist is.

Comment: turned out a reboot of the mac solved the problem. What I was doing was okay. I'm too new at Swift and Xcode so I assumed the problem was mine (it usually is) and just kept trying every different suggestion I could find and nothing worked - well, except for the reboot.

Comment: @BrianReinhold Sometimes reboot is the best option when nothing works :). Anyway good to know, you got it working.